# MVC Implimentation iOS, When & How?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I know MVC is very important to follow however all of the tutorials I see on YouTube and else where never include the model. How do I know when to implement it? Why do people generally only use the VC and View? Is Firebase an extension of the model or does it replace the model?

I've seen some videos that are pretty basic like a calculator that have a model, like the Stanford Course on iTunes U, but some are complex like chat applications that do everything in the VC with no model at all.

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_model_view_controller

Answer (score 1):

Apps aren't really meant for MVC due to their changing nature in my experience.  The best way that I've seen it described is that a proper MVC is able to be stripped and then made into a template.  If you can turn your app into a template anyone can use, you have a good model, and then build the View Controllers off that.  With a calculator, you can template it and build another calculator, or a page of buttons that do other things (a calculator can be quickly changed to a phone pad for example).  If what you have is easily templatable, then use MVC, otherwise, just do everything from the VC